# collision of two images problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uiimageview, collision-detection

Here is my code :

```
-(void)collision {
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame,center.frame)) {
        center.alpha=0.1;
    }
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:7.0f];
    [ball setCenter:CGPointMake(200, 100)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(collision) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

My problem is that when viewDidLoad "center.alpha=0.1" but "center" and "ball" have not collided yet , I don't know why, I think it is due to the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are scheduling the call to collision 0.01 seconds after the line is executed at the end of viewDidLoad.  But the view hasn't been displayed yet and so it could take longer than 0.01 seconds to display the view.

Try `viewDidAppear`

Having said that, I think you are not clear on the purpose of the animtions in iOS.  These are not for calculating collision detection - they are just for moving things from a start point to an end point over a set time.  I would suggest you read the Apple docs on the animation system.

Comment: yes but if I don't use UIView animation it is very hard. Because the "imageView" is created at a random position and it move to the center of the screen, how can you do that with the timers , it is very difficult.

Comment: I think you need to give a bit more description of what you are trying to achieve.  There is code missing from your question (where you are initialising ball and center, for example) that would help answer your original question.  But I think your real issue might be with the approach you are taking to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: my code is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505834/replace-a-uiview-animation-by-a-timer-animation

Answer (score 1):

Although the animation takes 7 seconds, `[ball setCenter:CGPointMake(200, 100)];`is set immediately and because of that `- (void)collision` probably sets your alpha to 0.1 before "ball" intersects with "center" in the animation.

Instead of UIView animations you could use a NSTimer to slowly change the center of "ball".

Comment: yes but I don't wanna use NSTimer because my programm must use UIView animations is there another solution ?

Comment: you can only get start and end position of an UIView animation, so you probably just can't use UIView animations for collision detection

Comment: yes but if I don't use UIView animation it is very hard. Because the "imageView" is created at a random position and it move to the center of the screen, how can you do that with the timers . Do you have a solution ?