# replace a UIview animation by a timer animation

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, timer, uiimageview

well here is my code :

```
- (CGPoint)randomPointSquare {
CGRect frame = [[self view] frame];

//CGFloat rand_x = ((float)arc4random() / (float)UINT_MAX) * (float)_window.frame.size.width;

NSInteger side = arc4random() / (UINT_MAX/4);
CGFloat offset = 0;

switch(side) {
    case 0: /* top */
        offset = ((float)arc4random() / (float)UINT_MAX) * (float)frame.size.width;
        return CGPointMake(offset, -10);

    case 1: /* bottom */
        offset = ((float)arc4random() / (float)UINT_MAX) * (float)frame.size.width;
        return CGPointMake(offset, frame.size.height-150);

    case 2: /* left */
        offset = ((float)arc4random() / (float)UINT_MAX) * (float)frame.size.height;
        return CGPointMake(-10, offset);

    default:
    case 3: /* right */
        offset = ((float)arc4random() / (float)UINT_MAX) * (float)frame.size.height;
        return CGPointMake(frame.size.width+170, offset);
}
}



-(void)createNewImageView {
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abouffer_03.png"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];


// Add it at a random point
[imageView setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];
[[self view] addSubview:imageView];

// Animate it into place
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:8.0f];
[imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(240, 160)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
 [imageView release];
}
```

SO as you can see there is a *UIView* animation, but now I want to change and replace it by a Timer. But I don't know how to do it . Well, if you know how to do it, don't forget that I want that the *imageView* is created at a random position and then it moves to the center of the screen. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than writing all the code for you, I'll give you some pointers that might help you change it (the best way of learning, I think).

First, when you create the position in the call to `randomPointSqaure`, store the point created as an instance variable.

```
theLocation = [self randomPointSquare];
```

Then set the location of the imageView to be this

```
[imageView setCenter:theLocation];
```

Calculate how far the object is from the point you want it to be (240, 160) and divide that by the amount of time you want it to move over.  For example, if your location is (0, 160) then it will be travelling 240 pixels.  If you want it over 10 seconds, it will be 24 pixels per second.  Save this in an instance variable as the "delta"

Now create a timer that calls a method to update the position

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(updatePosition) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And then create the `updatePosition` method

```
- (void)updatePosition {
    ...
    // Calculate the new position
    // delta is divided by 100 as the timer runs every 0.01 second
    // and delta was calculated previously as being distance per second
    theLocation = theLocation + (delta / 100);
    ...
    [imageView setCenter:theLocation];

    // Check if the location is at the "collision point" and do whatever if it is
    if (theLocation.x == 240 && theLocation.y == 160) {
       // We've hit the "collision point"
    }
}
```

This should hopefully give you some ideas on how you can do it with a Timer instead of animations.  This is how a game would perform the same thing - you just update the positions of the objects in small little steps and then check for collisions etc each time.

Comment: I don't really understand the part :"Calculate how far the object is from the point you want it to be (240, 160) and divide that by the amount of time you want it to move over" because I don't know where the image position is created because it is a random position. can you develop your code please .

Comment: You've got the random position that it was created at - see `theLocation = [self randomPointSquare];` To calculate the distance from (240,160), you could simply subtract the x locations and y locations from each other.  So if theLocation.x was 120 and theLocation.y was 100, then the distance would be 120 along the x and 60 along the y.

Comment: yes I understand that but what I need is to know how to calculate the distance and the coordinates... if you give me a sample code it will be easier for me to understand :/

Comment: As I said in the previous comment - just subtract the x locations and y locations from each other.  The location you want to start from is a CGPoint and the location you want to travel to is a CGPoint.  So just subtract the x of one from the x of the other and likewise the y.  This will give you the distance in each.  Then just divide those distances by the time you want it to take to move (in seconds).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether you want to display image randomly set after few seconds, or you want translation animation from moving random position to center position. Anyways, I have put both options over here

1)

First of all, once you create image view call function below:

```
-(void)randomlySetImage{
    int x = arc4random() % (int)self.view.frame.size.width;
    int y = arc4random() % (int)self.view.frame.size.height;

   imageView.center = CGPointMake(x,y);

   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                    target:self 
                                  selector:@selector(randomlySetImage) 
                                  userInfo:nil 
                                   repeats:YES];
}
```

2)

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];

CAKeyframeAnimation *positionAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
CGMutablePathRef positionPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(positionPath, NULL, randomX ,  randomY );
CGPathAddLineToPoint(positionPath, NULL, self.view.center.x , self.view.center.y);
positionAnimation.path = positionPath;

[[imageView layer] addAnimation:positionAnimation forKey:@"PositionAnimation"];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: where do randomX and randomY come from, is there a method ?

Comment: You can find randomX and randomY  int randomX = arc4random() % (int)self.view.frame.size.width;
    int randomY = arc4random() % (int)self.view.frame.size.height;

Comment: yes but I had already done a method for a random position and I wanted to have thes random position not yours, is it possible to associate mine to yours

Comment: I think, you want to move image view with timer using your method, but this will become static instead, if you set starting point and ending point and let delegate this task to CAAnimation class, which will handle animation.

Comment: I use your code but xcode gives error:"CATransaction undeclared" "CAKeyframeAnimation undeclared " and "kCATransactionAnimationDuration undeclared". I don't know how to declare them